# Logical table of P->Q math statements

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In a course I had, we have been given two statements P and Q and their "boolean table" :
[image]

While I completely understand *P and Q* and *P or Q* values, **I can't understand the first two lines for P->Q, why is the result true even when P is false ?**

Thank you.

Comment: This is a common question around these parts.  http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=if+p+then+q

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry, didn't knew how to formulate it in the search engine.

Comment: Basically "if P then Q" does not imply any form of a causality.  It's just the statement "whenever P is true, Q is true".  It is equivalent to "it's not the case that P is true and Q is false".  Basically if P is false "whenever P is true, Q is true" is vacuously true because we can't have the case that P is true and Q is false so when P is false $P \rightarrow Q$ is "not false"..

Comment: @fleablood Oh thank you so much, yes, actually I was considering only P, not the whole statement (P->Q) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it this way.  If $P$ is true, we test $P \rightarrow Q$ by seeing whether $Q$ is true or not.

In other words $P\rightarrow Q$ is falsified when $P$ is true but $Q$ is false.  If $P$ is not true, we can't do any such falisifying verification.

So if $P$ is false, then $P \rightarrow Q$ is ... not false.

Comment: Clear and concise answer ! Thank you so much !